# I have account in ionic 2 web site but when i try to login to :http://apps.ionic.io/login I get Error

Tags: ionic-framework, authentication, ionic2, unauthorized

I register new account in ionic web site ([Ionic 2](https://dashboard.ionicjs.com/signup))
after that when i try to login here : [ionic apps login page](http://apps.ionic.io/login)
i get this error:

> Please enter a correct email and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

I have same problem in ionic view app for android.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I sent email to ionic support team and they say can not login to apps.ionic.io/login becuase this is thier legacy .
and they say can not login from android device yet and say new version of ionic view app is comming soon.